# Date Time format and adding time to date

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a data file that contains the evendata such as event starting date (**Date**), starting time (**KOTime**) and event time (**EveTime**).
The following is the sample of data.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Date'] = ['2018/08/12','2018/08/12','2018/08/12','2018/08/12','2018/08/12','2018/08/12']
df['KOTime'] = ['12:30:00','12:30:00','12:30:00','12:30:00','12:30:00','12:30:00']
df['EveTime'] = ['04:50:00','01:03:00','1900-01-03 05:22:00','1900-01-02 16:04:00','1900-01-01 10:28:00','1900-01-01 16:23:00']
```

**Evetime** is not formatted in the raw data file as can be seen in the data.
if the Evetime is greater than 24 hours, it is shown as 1900-01-xx .
If we look at the 3rd value of **EveTime**, it is shown as 1900-01-03 05:22:00.
It is supposed to be **2018/08/12 13:47:22**. 
I want to create a new column that contains **Date** and **EveTime**  and the expected output is as follow:

```
2018/08/12 12:34:50
2018/08/12 12:31:03
2018/08/12 13:47:22
2018/08/12 13:34:04
2018/08/12 12:40:28
2018/08/12 12:46:23
```

Can anyone suggest me how to do to get the format mentioned above?

Comment: Sorry, `1900-01-03 05:22:00` is `3 hours`, `5 minutes` and `22 sec` ? Or something else?

Comment: Hi Jez, it means that take 03 from 1900-01-03. 03 in this context equivalent to 72 (3 *24). 05:22:00 is equivalent to 5 minutes and 22 seconds. it means 1900-01-03 and 05:22:00 is 77:05:22 
if I add Date and EveTime, i expected to have 2018/08/12 13:47:22

Comment: hmm, I get different output, `1900-01-03 05:22:00` is `3 days 5 minutes and 22 sec`, so if add it to `2018/08/12  12:30:00` get `2018-08-15 12:35:22`. Can you check it?

Comment: Hi Jez,
In fact the only different is date, my expected outcome is 2018-08-**12** (12:30:00 + 77:22:00), 12:30:00 refers to 12 hours 30 minutes
here 77:22:00 (  mm:ss:nn) refers to 77 minutes 22 seconds and 0 nn.
if we add 12:30:00 and 77:22:00, it gives us 13:47:22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need convert values to `timedelta`s and add to `datetime`s column:

```
#convert to numeric
num = pd.to_numeric(df['EveTime'].str[-11:-8], errors='coerce')
#convert to timedeltas with seconds
td1 = pd.to_timedelta(np.where(num > 1, num, 0) * 24 * 60, unit='s')
td2 =  pd.to_timedelta('00:' + df['EveTime'].str[-8:-3])
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] + ' ' + df['KOTime']) + td1 + td2
print (df)
         Date    KOTime              EveTime                date
0  2018/08/12  12:30:00             04:50:00 2018-08-12 12:34:50
1  2018/08/12  12:30:00             01:03:00 2018-08-12 12:31:03
2  2018/08/12  12:30:00  1900-01-03 05:22:00 2018-08-12 13:47:22
3  2018/08/12  12:30:00  1900-01-02 16:04:00 2018-08-12 13:34:04
4  2018/08/12  12:30:00  1900-01-01 10:28:00 2018-08-12 12:40:28
5  2018/08/12  12:30:00  1900-01-01 16:23:00 2018-08-12 12:46:23

print (td1)
TimedeltaIndex(['00:00:00', '00:00:00', '01:12:00', '00:48:00', '00:00:00',
                '00:00:00'],
               dtype='timedelta64[ns]', freq=None)

print (td2)
0   00:04:50
1   00:01:03
2   00:05:22
3   00:16:04
4   00:10:28
5   00:16:23
Name: EveTime, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: Working on your solution.

Comment: @Zephyr - What about last 2 values?

Comment: Hi Jez,
The first 4 looks ok.
The last two
12:30:00 + 10:28:00, i expect 12:40:28
12:30:00+ 16:23:00, i expect 12:46:23

Comment: So there is no added `1 * 24` minutes?

Comment: Yes for 1, we do not need that. only >1 required 1*24.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks. It works with the sample data.
When I applied to main data, it showed some error such as :
expected hh:mm:ss format

Comment: @Zephyr - Is possible sent me to my email in my profile `df[['Date','KOTime','EveTime'].to_csv('file.csv')` ? Because it seems some data problem.

Comment: Sure, I just sent out.Thanks

Comment: I found some of the data in EveTime as 04:22. I think we just need to add to make it 04:22:00 format

Comment: @Zephyr - Now it working with real data, one `np.where` by length was necessary. I hope it working nice now ;)

Comment: @Zephyr - Check email with solution.